# Sound Proofing For use of power tools in a room located in a house located in a residential area in the utmost clandestine fashion possible

Tags: sound

As the title as pretty much covered, I am a night owl and my mother goes mental if I do anything more than type on my computer. What do I buy from a the local hardware store would be a huge help

Comment: Please try to edit your question with a shorter title and describe your question inside. Provide house plans or measurements, wall material, what kind of tools you use etc, if you want to have a chance to get an answer. Having said that this is not a sound proofing forum. But someone might help.

Comment: This is way too broad to even start on.What's the building made of? How much physical separation do you already have? How much can you modify it? What's your budget? What kind of power tools [ie drilling walls has zero method of isolation] Sounds insulation requires mass & air-gapping. If you can't add those, you can't isolate it.

Comment: It's not an acoustic problem you have, it's a mother problem. Go the the pharmacy and buy her some earplugs.

Comment: Well I guess I should really google the subject before asking a stack exchange question, I have a chronological disablility

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, forget it.  Short of major structural work, you won't be able to reduce the sound of power tools enough to satisfy your mother.